# What to do when the program executes too fast for hotspots to be found. (Intel vTune Profiler)

Tags: c, profiler, intel-vtune

I am trying to profile a c application to find hotspots in the code. However, I have an issue where the program completes too fast for vTune to properly collect the data.

I can not change the original program in anyway so trying to make it take longer is not an option.

Outside of getting a worse computer is there any way or trick to get vTune to profile the program so that hotspots are displayed?

I am new to vTune so simple instructions are appreciated.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Do nothing. If a program completes quickly (and correctly), there is no problem to be solved.

Comment: I understand that this is the practical answer but, I need the performance metrics.

Comment: Why paint yourself into a corner? Just wrap a million-x loop around it, and divide the results by a million. By the way, the "hotspot" concept is baloney. If you really want it to go faster, you need to see what it's doing that isn't necessary. I do [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).

Comment: or maybe you could run it under one of the interpreters...  That will give you 1 or 2 orders of magnitude slowdown.

Comment: We apologize as this is a known cause and the only solution is to increase your workload of your application(which is impossible in your case as you mentioned). [Here's](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/troubleshooting/error-message-cannot-open-data.html) your troubleshooting steps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot change the size of workload for the application, you can try to change following options in VTune:

1. Set [finalization mode](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/analyze-performance/control-data-collection/finalization.html) to Full mode. VTune will load all collected samples in this mode.
2. If you can use [Sampling Driver](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/vtune-help/top/installation/sep-driver.html) (administrative privileges are required to install it), you can run Hotspots analysis in Hardware Event-Based Sampling mode and set a minimum value for the sampling interval: 0.01 ms. It will increase the number of collected samples during the analysis. But, it will also increase the collection overhead.

[image: VTune screenshot with the options to analyze small applications]